# connect from website to MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Please forgive in advance as I’m new to PHP and MySQL. I’m using phpMyAdmin v3.4 and MySQL (server version) v5.5. Both the MySQL DB and the website are hosted by JustHost.

I’ve constructed a simple database in MySQL and can’t seem to verify whether I have a connection to it from my website! I’m certain the db_host, db_username, db_password and db_name are correct so I guess the problem is in the syntax of the script (sorry!) i.e. as It’s as though the PHP part of the scrip is completely ignored. I’ve built the script from tutorials and examples. I’m not actually ‘calling’ the script, I simply have the following pasted directly into the HTML webpage (nothing else is on the page and the web pages are JustHost provided templates). You can see I’ve toyed with error_reporting (the php.ini file by default has error_reporting=Off).

Even if I change say the db_name to an incorrect spelling, then refresh the webpage, I still don’t get anything echoed to the screen.  The only output echoed to the screen on refresh is the HTML title: PHP call DB. Thanks in anticipation.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP connect to DB</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    //ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting=On;
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_username = "Peter";
    $db_password = "passwd";
    $db_name = "Res";
    @mysql_select ("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_password") or die ("could not connect to my sql");
    @mysql_select_db ("$db_name") or die ("No database");
    echo "successful connection";
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what do you see? "Could not connect"?

Comment: The `mysql_` functions have been deprecated and should not be used anymore. Please use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: `error_reporting=On` won’t have an effect; actually, I think this will even be an error. Try `ini_set('error_reporting', 1)` instead.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Also, I wouldn't advise using mysql_ functions.  mysqli_ procedural is very similar however.

Comment: The first thing to know, is that mysql_ functions are now deprecated, meaning you shouldn't use them. What you should use now is PDO, or mySQLi (mySQL improved).

Here is a great article on how to connect to a database with PDO.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/

Comment: I will make the suggested changes and report back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_select()` isn't a function.

you are looking for `mysql_connect()`
https://www.php.net/manual/function.mysql-connect.php

that said. you should use the mysqli functions
https://www.php.net/manual/intro.mysqli.php

Comment: I will make the suggested changes and report back